# Get Project Root Directory Name in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, path, asp.net-mvc-5

I can't seem to find an answer anywhere on how to get the name of the first folder of my project.

So for Example I have a BaseSite folder and inside that BaseSite folder is where my solution file sits, in there I have many projects.  I need to retrive the "BaseSite" name and only that.

I have found various examples with `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString();` but that gives you the full path and my folder name is buried in there.

Same with: `Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/somedata.xml");`

Comment: You could figure it out pretty easily by using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString()` and then splitting on `/`

Comment: @mituw16 Seemed like an overkill, was wondering if there was a function that does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

```
    //this path will return current project folder
    string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

     DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);

    string infy = info.Parent.FullName; //this will give you the full path of project folder.
```

if you have to go one level up then add

`info.Parent.Parent.FullName`

And if you have to go one level down to subdirectory. Then use

```
     DirectoryInfo[] directoryinfo = info.GetDirectories("SearchPattern or your subdirectory name");
    string subdirectory = directoryinfo.FirstOrDefault().FullName;
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check. It will return the base directory.

```
var BaseDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~")).Parent.Name;
```

And

```
new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/somedata.xml")).Parent.Name;
```

Comment: I'm not Looking for Solution Folder, but the actual physical folder that holds the full project

Comment: Does your folder physically exist in file system ??

Comment: Yes it physically  exists in the file system